# SQL Prepared Statement & returning type

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, statements

I have just created a method in my class file, were I insert data into my sql database.

1) Are these prepared statements correct?
2) I need to return a type car for the method (Where could this be done)?
.....As the error I get at the moment is the method must return a type Car (Car is the name of the class file)

```
public Car addVehicle(String aLicense, int aJourneys, String aUsername, String aPassword) {
    Car c = new Car();
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        String query = " insert into eflow.registration (cLicense, cJourneys, cUsername, cPassword)"
                + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString(1, aLicense);
        preparedStmt.setInt(2, aJourneys);
        preparedStmt.setString(3, aUsername);
        preparedStmt.setString(4, aPassword);

        preparedStmt.execute();

        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());

    }
    return c;

}
```

Calling the method returns an error that the method is not applicable for arguments

```
//int addingID = Integer.parseInt(enteringID.getText());
                String addingReg = enteringReg.getText();
                int addingJourneys = Integer.parseInt(enteringJourneys.getText());
                String addingUsername = enteringUsername.getText();
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                String addingPassword = enteringPassword.getText();
                Car newCar = new Car(addingReg, addingJourneys, addingUsername, addingPassword);
                int addStatus = myCar.addVehicle(newCar);
                if (addStatus == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vehicle Added");
                    enteringID.setText("(eg. 1-999)");
                    enteringReg.setText("(eg. - 162-MH-749)");
                    enteringJourneys.setText("(eg. 7)");
                    enteringUsername.setText("(eg. - username@domain.com)");
                    enteringPassword.setText("");
                }

                else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please Try Again");
                }
            } catch (Exception f) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, Please Try Again");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No they're not. For one you are not supposed to add `'` characters when setting Strings to `PreparedStatement`, unless you want those to be included in the actual value.

Comment: If you want your method to return a Car object, you'll have to create an instance of class Car and return it. It's that easy. Car c = new Car(); return c;

Comment: What would I need to do to alter this?

Comment: Also, the first parameter is at index 1, the second at index 2, etc. You're using 1, 5, 1, 1 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4. Why don't you test your own code? You would know that it's incorrect. You're also creating a statement for nothing, ignoring exceptionsinstead of throwing them to let the caller know that something bad happened, and not using the try-with-resources statement to ensure your connection is always closed.

Comment: Numbers have been altered as the code has not been compiled yet as I am not able to return what @Rens suggested as it is showing as cannot be returned as a variable at the line return c;

Comment: Declare `Car c = new Car();` before the try-catch block.

Comment: Thank you for that advice, it worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

This is not a final answer for your question, but purely to clarify my comment.

If you want your method to return a Car object, you'll have to create an instance of class Car and return it:

```
public Car addVehicle(String aLicense, int aJourneys, String aUsername, String aPassword) {
try {        
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
    statement = conn.createStatement();
    String query = " insert into eflow.registration (cLicense, cJourneys, cUsername, cPassword)"
            + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStmt.setString(1, "'" + aLicense + "'");
    preparedStmt.setInt(2, aJourneys);
    preparedStmt.setString(3, "'" + aUsername + "'");
    preparedStmt.setString(4, "'" + aPassword + "'");

    preparedStmt.execute();

    conn.close();

    Car c = new Car();
    //Do anything with the car object that you like.
    //for example: c.setColor("blue");
    return c;

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Got an exception!");
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    //kayaman is correct here: we still need to return something here in order to be able to compile
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Would anybody have advice on what way I should be passing in the strings to the database?

Answer (score 0):

**Separate the logic!**

Use this class to retrieve connection where you need it:

```
public class DatabaseConnection
{
    private static final String CONN_URL = "some connection url";
    private static Connection instance = null;

    static
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized Connection getInstance() throws SQLException
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_URL);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Use it in your function like this:

```
public Car addVehicle(String aLicense, int aJourneys, String aUsername, String aPassword)
{
    String sql = "insert into eflow.registration (cLicense, cJourneys, cUsername, cPassword) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try (Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getInstance(); PreparedStatement prepStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql))
    {
        Car successfulAdd = new Car();

        prepStatement.setString(1, aLicense);
        prepStatement.setInt(2, aJourneys);
        prepStatement.setString(3, aUsername);
        prepStatement.setString(4, aPassword);

        if (prepStatement.execute())
        {
            return successfulAdd;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have added another class to my question were I am calling the method to write to the database if anybody could assists

Comment: @user3079838 Wait adding to database? You've already done it haven't you?

Comment: The information in the method required strings etc added from a different class. I have got it to work now. Thanks for your help